# How can I omit double quote when `cd F:\folder_xxx` in wsl2?

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have found below ways:

```
wcd() { cd `wslpath "$1"`; }
cdw() { cd "$(wslpath "$1")"; }
```

They need add double quote around a path:

```
wcd "F:\folder_xxx"
```

Which is not comfortable for me .

I'd like

```
wcd F:\folder_xxx
```

How do I achieve my goal ?

Comment: Use forward slashes instead. Backslash is for escaping. To get a literal backslash, you need to escape it or quote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [user1686](https://superuser.com/users/1686/user1686), I learned magic alias.

Though it doesn't work on zsh.

### first problem is how to get correct last history

1. history 1 got all history
2. history -1 got previous line of history in magic alias ( but corrent in terminal)
3. so I change it to `tail -n -1 ~/.zsh_history`

### second is the regex

1. `^\s*[0-9]\+\s\+([^)]\+)\s\+$1\s\+//"` doesn't match the case , test on https://sed.js.org/index.html
2. change to `"s/.\+$1\s\+//"`

### finally

add below to `~/.zshrc`, you can use `echow` to do magic alias testing

```bsh
_thiscommand() { tail -n -1 ~/.zsh_history  | sed "s/.\+$1\s\+//"; }

_real_wcd() { cd `wslpath "$1"`; }
alias wcd='_real_wcd "$(_thiscommand wcd)" #'

_echo_wcd() { echo "$1" }
alias echow='_echo_wcd "$(_thiscommand echow)" #'
```

then `wcd F:\xxxx` works!

Answer (score 1):

Use a [magic alias](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/aliases.html).

1. Define a helper function that pulls out the last line from shell history:

   ```
   _thiscommand() { history 1 | sed "s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s\+([^)]\+)\s\+$1\s\+//"; }
   ```
2. Give a different name to your function that does the thing:

   ```
   _real_wcd() { cd "`wslpath "$1"`"; }
   ```
3. Define an alias that ends with a `#`, making the whole text technically a *comment* that isn't affected by backslash expansion:

   ```
   alias wcd='_real_wcd "$(_thiscommand wcd)" #'
   ```

Note that this will suppress *all* special shell syntax processing, including $variables, chained && commands, "quotes", and such. Everything after the word `wcd` will become the parameter.

---

Alternative: Redefine the [readline Enter key handler](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/aliases.html) to automatically add the quotes.

1. Define a function that'll make edits to $READLINE_LINE:

   ```
   _fix_wcd_quotes() {
       if [[ $READLINE_LINE == wcd* ]]; then
           local before=${#READLINE_LINE}
           READLINE_LINE=$(echo "$READLINE_LINE" | sed 's/wcd \([^"].*\)/wcd "\1"/')
           local after=${#READLINE_LINE}
           READLINE_POINT=$[READLINE_POINT+(after-before)]
       fi
   }
   ```
2. Bind a key to it (e.g. <kbd>Alt+1</kbd>):

   ```
   bind -m emacs -x '"\e1": _fix_wcd_quotes'
   ```
3. Bind the 'RETURN' event to issue that key before issuing a newline:

   ```
   bind -m emacs 'RETURN: "\e1\n"'
   ```

I think this is technically worse than the previous suggestion, because as soon as it goes wrong and quotes something you didn't want quoted, it'll make you think *you* typed the extra quotes yourself.

---

Alternative: Define a readline macro that inserts quotes around the current word. (Untested; I only pulled it out from the bash(1) manual.)

1. Add this binding to `~/.inputrc`:

   ```
   $if Bash
   # Quote the current or previous word
   "\C-xq": "\eb\"\ef\""
   $endif
   ```
2. Use <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd>, <kbd>Q</kbd> to invoke it.

Comment: `history 1` doesn't get last history  in zsh .  I tried `history -1` in zsh , but it actually got previous command instead of current `magic alias` .

Comment: I tried the `echo-literally-helper` example from that link, doesn't work , only show previous history .